# How to create a moving pointer in android surface view?

Tags: android, surfaceview, gesture

I need to create a project in which i need to use a moving pointer while writing on a surface view. 
My project write on a surface view which i can save as an image and re-use after saving it. So i need to point a pointer while i write on my view. How can i create this moving pointer in my project?

Comment: You mean like Mouse Pointer ?

Comment: No, It should like a pen or some other shapes which travels with the letters or shapes which i draw.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your `SurfaceView` into `RelativeLayout`, you can put another views in the same view group. Every new view will be placed in front of yout SurfaceView. This way you can draw any pointer for example with moving `ImageView`. Do you mean something like this?